# How do I add a range system for a guessing game in Python?

Tags: python

this is my first time asking on stack overflow and I'm quite new to programming. I just have a question on how to make 'guessing ranges.
For example:
Num is the number you have to guess

```py
if guess > Num + 1 between Num + 5  
 print("That's really close")
```

But I don't really know what to code to make it work, or if it's even possible.
Basically what I want to do is to make the game print a text when you guess and it's near the Answer at a certain range e.g. 5

This is my code so far, and it works as expected:

```py
#Author: Sunya Hatch-Barnwell
#Date: 6/02/2021
#Program: NumberGuess
import random
Guess = 0
Num = 1
choice = 0
min = 1
max = 0

print("Welcome to Number Guess")
max = int(input("What's the highest number you want?: "))

Num = random.randint(min, max)

while Guess != Num:

    Guess = int(input("Guess the number: "))
    if Guess == Num:
        print("That's correct the number was " ,Num )
    elif Guess > Num:
        print("Too high! ")
    elif Guess < Num:
        print("Too low! ")
    else:
        print("Please type a number! ")
```

Comment: Under what condition will you get to "Please type a number!"?

Answer (score 0):

If you mean "in a certain range" as in I was 4 numbers away from the guess, you could do it like this:

```py
if abs(num - guess) < 5:
   print("You're within 4 numbers! Keep trying!")
```

The `abs()` function is necessary, seeing as we can't use negative values for a distance from something in this context.

You can also remove the `else` statement in your code. Not only is the variable initialized (so the variable will *always* be greater or less than the guess), but the `input` forces a value in anyway before the conditionals.

Comment: Thanks  so much, the code works now. I'll just have to learn what abs does which shouldn't be too hard.

Comment: the `abs()` function returns the absolute value of any integer.
ex. `-5` to `5`

Answer (score -1):

So basically your looking for something like this?

```
min = 1
max = int(input('the maximum number?'))
cn = random.randint(min, max)

guess = int(input('guess the number!'))
if guess > cn:
    print('too high!')
elif cn > guess:
    print('too low!')
elif guess == cn:
    print('correct!')
```